# Why is $f(E)\cap f(F)\subset f(E\cap F)$ not true?

Tags: analysis

Let $f:A\to B$ and $E,F\subset A$ be subsets.
Then it holds $$f(E\cap F) \subset f(E)\cap f(F).$$

Why is $f(E)\cap f(F)\subset f(E\cap F)$ not true?

Comment: Consider a constant function and $E$ and $F$ non-empty and disjoint.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the following simple example: $f:ℝ↦ℝ, x↦42$.
Then let the subsets be $E=\{0\}$ and $F=\{1\}$.

Now it is $E∩F=\emptyset$, and thus $f(E∩F)=\emptyset$.
But with $f(E)=\{42\}$ and $f(F)=\{42\}$ it is $$f(E)∩f(F)=\{42\}\neq\emptyset.$$